# Accessing String on Node.js Server from Ajax Post Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

This is my first project working with ajax and node.js and so far all my POST requests have been done through form submissions.

I am now trying to use `$.ajax` to send a `POST` and pass the string 'cocktailid' for the `server.js` to use after a div `click()`.

I was wondering what the easiest way to accomplish this would be.

Ajax code

```
$(".col-sm").click(function(){
  //Append to console a log that cocktail div has been clicked.
  console.log("Cocktail Clicked.");
  console.log(this);

  //Create variable to hold id of cocktail div clicked
  var cocktailid = $(this).attr('id');
  cocktailid = cocktailid.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
  cocktailid = cocktailid.replace(/'/g, '');
  alert(cocktailid);

  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/adddrink',
   data: { "field1": cocktailid},
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   contentType: "application/json",
   success: function(data) {
    console.log('success');
    console.log(cocktail + 'sent.');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
   }
  });
})
};
```

Server.js

```
app.post('/adddrink', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);
});
```

I have tried to send the data in a few different formats and had different problems, currently my server is showing the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/home/codio/workspace/CocktailMixerGroupRepo/website/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)
    at parse (/home/codio/workspace/CocktailMixerGroupRepo/website/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /home/codio/workspace/CocktailMixerGroupRepo/website/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/home/codio/workspace/CocktailMixerGroupRepo/website/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/home/codio/workspace/CocktailMixerGroupRepo/website/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/codio/workspace/CocktailMixerGroupRepo/website/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
```

Right now I just want to show I can access the string on the node server.

I've tried looking around for a solution and after my attempts I expect I've really over complicated what I am trying to achieve, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use: `JSON.stringify` on `data`

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/adddrink',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "field1": cocktailid
  }),
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

Without it the payload is `field1=yes` instead of `{"field1":"yes"}` that's why you're getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0` because you weren't posting a valid JSON.

For a more detailed error, you can add an error handling middleware **after** `body-parser` to handle JSON errors.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {

    // Body parser middleware Error
    if(err instanceof SyntaxError) {

        // err.body contains the actual body that was posted
        // which won't be a valid JSON.
        console.error(`Invalid JSON: ${err.body}`);

        return res
            .status(400) // Bad request
            .send({
                message: 'Invalid JSON'
            });

    }

    next();
});
```